# Flask - Decorator for Basic Auth

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, flask

I'm trying to create decorator which will redirect to specified path if not logged in.

Decorator:

```
def secured(path):
    @wraps(path)
    def wrapper(f, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'loggedin' in session:
            if session.get('loggedin'):
                return f(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                redirect(path)
        else:
            session['loggedin'] = False
            redirect(path)
    return wrapper
```

Login function:

```
def val_cred(username, password):
    return username == 'login' and password == 'password'
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    auth = request.authorization
    if not auth.username or not auth.password or not val_cred(auth.username, auth.password):
        return 'bad credentials', 401
    session['loggedin'] = True
    return redirect("/hello")
```

Example of secured path:

```
@app.route('/hello')
@secured('/')
def hello():
    return 'you are logged in'
```

Before I created decorator with static path which takes no arguments and it worked well, so I thought it's syntax problem, but Flask states it's something else

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/daftcode-flask/app.py", line 31, in <module>
    @secured('/')
  File "C:/daftcode-flask/app.py", line 14, in wrapper
    if 'loggedin' in session:
  ...

    RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.
```

How can I make it work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an mistake in `secured` decorator. You forgot to add one more function inside(see: `def _secured(f)`):

```
def secured(path):
    def _secured(f):
        @wraps(path)
        def __secured(*args, **kwargs):
            # Note! I didn't check your functionality
            if 'loggedin' in session:
                if session.get('loggedin'):
                    return f(*args, **kwargs)
                else:
                    redirect(path)
            else:
                session['loggedin'] = False
                redirect(path)
        return __secured
    return _secured
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works like charm now. Thank you very much.